# Mongodb update/find query not using correct index

Tags: mongodb

We moved db servers, where the new server is technically faster and has bigger SSD,RAM and CPU. it has the same version of mongodb 2.6. but my update query is slower than it should be. OLD DB: 0.225s, New DB: 0.3s - 1.5s. so its unstable.

```
Update Query ($upsert: true):
{
        "_id.date" : "2016-10-03",
        "_id.week" : "Monday",
        "_id.hour" : "19",
        "_id.s_id" : "xxxx",
        "_id.c_id" : "yyyy",
        "_id.domain" : "pldt.com",
        "_id.l_id" : "zzzzz",
        "_id.o_id" : [ 
            {
                "or_id" : "wwww"
            }, 
            {
                "o_id" : "rrrrrr"
            }
        ],
        "_id.browser" : "Chrome",
        "_id.platform" : "Android",
        "_id.isp" : "PLDT",
        "_id.org" : "PLDT",
        "_id.country" : "China",
        "_id.city" : "",
        "_id.n_id" : NumberLong(5),
        "_id.device_type" : "mobile",
        "_id.cd" : "0",
        "_id.t_a_id" : "423525",
        "_id.c1" : "1",
        "_id.c2" : "2",
        "_id.c3" : "3",
        "_id.c4" : "4",
        "_id.set" : "1",
        "_id.device_name" : "Samsung Galaxy Note 4"
    }
```

I have a compound index for that. but it doesnt seem to use it.

```
{
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id.date" : 1.0000000000000000,
            "_id.week" : 1.0000000000000000,
            "_id.hour" : 1.0000000000000000,
            "_id.s_id" : 1.0000000000000000,
            "_id.c_id" : 1.0000000000000000,
            "_id.domain" : 1.0000000000000000,
            "_id.l_id" : 1.0000000000000000,
            "_id.o_id" : 1.0000000000000000,
            "_id.browser" : 1.0000000000000000,
            "_id.platform" : 1.0000000000000000,
            "_id.isp" : 1.0000000000000000,
            "_id.org" : 1.0000000000000000,
            "_id.country" : 1.0000000000000000,
            "_id.city" : 1.0000000000000000,
            "_id.n_id" : 1.0000000000000000,
            "_id.device_type" : 1.0000000000000000,
            "_id.cloaked" : 1.0000000000000000,
            "_id.t_a_id" : 1.0000000000000000,
            "_id.c1" : 1.0000000000000000,
            "_id.c2" : 1.0000000000000000,
            "_id.c3" : 1.0000000000000000,
            "_id.c4" : 1.0000000000000000,
            "_id.set" : 1.0000000000000000,
            "_id.device_name" : 1.0000000000000000
        },
    "name" : "upsert_20160804",
    "ns" : "test2.map_collections1",
    "background" : true
}
```

I do have a few compound index also. and when I run explain() it uses a different index.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id.date_1__id.c_id_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 29789,
    "nscanned" : 29789,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 134802,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 148948,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 1163,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 527,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "_id.date" : [ 
            [ 
                "2016-10-03", 
                "2016-10-03"
            ]
        ],
        "_id.c_id" : [ 
            [ 
                "yyyy", 
                "yyyy"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "mongo:27017",
    "filterSet" : false,
    "stats" : {
        "type" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
        "works" : 29791,
        "yields" : 1163,
        "unyields" : 1163,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "advanced" : 1,
        "needTime" : 29788,
        "needFetch" : 0,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "children" : [ 
            {
                "type" : "FETCH",
                "works" : 29790,
                "yields" : 1163,
                "unyields" : 1163,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "advanced" : 1,
                "needTime" : 29788,
                "needFetch" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                "forcedFetches" : 0,
                "matchTested" : 1,
                "children" : [ 
                    {
                        "type" : "IXSCAN",
                        "works" : 29790,
                        "yields" : 1163,
                        "unyields" : 1163,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "advanced" : 29789,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needFetch" : 0,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "keyPattern" : "{ _id.date: 1, _id.c_id: 1 }",
                        "isMultiKey" : 0,
                        "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['_id.date']: [\"2016-10-03\", \"2016-10-03\"], field #1['_id.c_id']: [\"yyyy\", \"yyyy\"]",
                        "yieldMovedCursor" : 0,
                        "dupsTested" : 0,
                        "dupsDropped" : 0,
                        "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                        "matchTested" : 0,
                        "keysExamined" : 29789,
                        "children" : []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am kinda lost what to do. Cause it should be just avg less than 200ms. and its hurting the performance of the script that using it.

Comment: That is one massive `_id` object and compound index. Do you really need all of those fields to uniquely identify your docs?

Comment: yes, its for map reduce purposes. 1 document could have 1k count. so it stores it on $value.